# Error reprojecting point cloud with liblas 1.8: "latitude or longitude exceeded limits"?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, error, lidar, liblas

I was previously reprojecting a point cloud in .las format using liblas 1.7.0 (with GeoTIFF 1.4.0 GDAL 1.10.1) as follows:

```
las2las /tmp/input.las --a_srs EPSG:4326 --t_srs EPSG:3857 --scale 0.001 0.001 0.001 --offset -13704940,4639778,0 --output /tmp/new.las
```

However, after upgrading to liblas 1.8.0 (with GeoTIFF 1.4.1 GDAL 1.11.3) I now get the following error which I believe indicates the scale factor and offset combination are not enough to cover the data range:

> ERROR 1: latitude or longitude exceeded limits
>   error: Could not project point for ReprojectionTransform::latitude or longitude exceeded limits

I have played about with the offset and scale factor and can get it to work only if I set the scale factors to `0.01` and remove the offset, e.g.:

```
las2las /tmp/input.las --a_srs EPSG:4326 --t_srs EPSG:3857 --scale 0.01 0.01 0.01 --output /tmp/next.las
```

Why am I getting this error with the newer version of liblas, and what should my reprojection command be?

For your information, here is the `lasinfo` for the input point cloud:

```
  Version:                     1.2
  Source ID:                   0
  Reserved:                    0
  Project ID/GUID:             '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  System ID:                   'libLAS Python API'
  Generating Software:         'libLAS 1.8.0'
  File Creation Day/Year:      149/2018
  Header Byte Size             227
  Data Offset:                 738
  Header Padding:              0
  Number Var. Length Records:  4
  Point Data Format:           2
  Number of Point Records:     20
  Compressed:                  False
  Number of Points by Return:  20 0 0 0 0
  Scale Factor X Y Z:          0.00000010000000 0.00000010000000 0.01000000000000
  Offset X Y Z:                -123.1140000 38.4250000 -100.00
  Min X Y Z:                   -123.1139429 38.4257008 -2.43
  Max X Y Z:                   -123.1130518 38.4263682 18.19
  Spatial Reference:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Comment: It sounds like there is a dodgy point outside the domain, use LAS2LAS -clip_to_bounding_box to remove points outside the specified bounding box.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be an option for this version of liblas unfortunately; I used the --extent option and specified the bounding box from lasinfo (which I assume does the same thing), but got the same result for the reprojection

Comment: Not in LibLAS, use LAS2LAS from LASTools to pre-clean your data before processing.. also, if you have tiled data the extents will no longer be rectangular to the Cartesian, LASTile can retile for neatness. If you haven't purchased LASTools I think the 'free' version will perform the bounding box clean but not the retile.

Comment: I don't currently have lastools for this project (running on linux), but can try that; any idea why this would suddenly stop working for the new version of liblas (this case worked fine previously)?

Comment: LibLAS is library, can you post the code that is causing the problem? From your question you're using LAS2LAS so why is it you say you don't have LASTools?

Comment: sorry, my mistake; here is my las2las version: `las2las (libLAS 1.8.0 with GeoTIFF 1.4.1 GDAL 1.11.3)`; but seems there is no clip_to_bounding_box parameter: `las2las -clip_to_bounding_box
error: unrecognised option '-clip_to_bounding_box'`

Comment: Try -keep_xy, it's an older option, supplying min_x min_y max_x max_y generously outside your processing area.. the dodgy points will be ouside -180 < X < 180 and -90 < Y < 90 so in your LAS2LAS line add -keep_xy -180 -90 180 90 and see if that helps.

Comment: didn't seem to work for me (but the -keep_xy was also not available, only the -e option for extents - available options here https://liblas.org/utilities/las2las.html); here's the input file I'm using if that helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxzip9a0350s7uv/input.las?dl=0

Comment: If that's the option then use -e -180 -90 180 90 to filter out points that are *over the horizon*.

Comment: I don't believe so - I actually used that post to get my original solution which worked in liblas 1.7, but it stopped working in 1.8.

Comment: I suggest you then, to make it clear in the beginning of your question why it is not a duplicate. But note in the other post Pete said in his last paragraph: "_Throwing out the offset is another weird quirk of libLAS that might actually be a bug (though I need to investigate further). Anyways, it shouldn't hurt your data to have that little offset in the roundtrip UTM file._". So why have used an offset? And when you say it worked using scale 0.01 and 0.01 without offset, do you mean the command line run and the projection was not accurate, or everything worked just fine?